# Export Error : Jenkins with Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am trying to export IPA from Jenkins. I have installed Jenkins in Unix. To build xcode project on this server, I have created a Slave node to build project.

Archive created successfully.

> `export
>   PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /usr/bin/touch -c /Users/tushar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*-ddkzgiiehnftznefgacmhnffkdiv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/OET/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/***.app.dSYM
>
> ** ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED **
>
> Finished: SUCCESS `

I am getting following error ---

> 2018-02-26 16:32:31.244 xcodebuild[15086:3083978] [MT]
>   IDEDistribution: Step failed: : Error
>   Domain=IDEDistributionSigningAssetStepErrorDomain Code=0 "Locating
>   signing assets failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Locating
>   signing assets failed.,
>   IDEDistributionSigningAssetStepUnderlyingErrors=(
>       "Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 \"\"***.app\" requires a provisioning profile.\"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=\"****.app\" requires a provisioning
>   profile., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add a profile to the
>   \"provisioningProfiles\" dictionary in your Export Options property
>   list.}" )} error: exportArchive: "****.app" requires a provisioning
>   profile.

Can some one please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the Provisioning File on your node machine and drag and drop it to Xcode installed on the node.

Furthermore, if you are using exportPlist file to sign the build then you have to mention the Provisioning Profile name in exportPlist file as well.